# remove consecutive duplicate with a certain values from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I want to remove duplicate values that are consecutive if their values are 'true' or 'false'. I know how to remove duplicate consecutive rows but not sure how to remove only values that have only values of 'true' or 'false' and not remove all the consecutive duplicate values.

```
cols =['col_b']
df = df.loc[(df[cols].shift() != df[cols]).any(axis=1)]
```

For example:

```
col_a   col_b
21     'true'
25      'true'
76      'abc'
89      'ttt'
99      'ttt'
210     'false'
211     'false'
212     'false'
```

And I need the following result:

```
col_a   col_b
21     'true'
76      'abc'
89      'ttt'
99      'ttt'
210     'false'
```

but it removes 'ttt' values which I need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try use `shift` with `cumsum` create the group, then do `duplicated` + the condition of false

```
s1 = df.col_b.ne(df.col_b.shift()).cumsum().duplicated()
s2 = df.col_b.isin(["'true'","'false'"])
df=df[~(s1&s2)]

df
   col_a    col_b
0     21   'true'
2     76    'abc'
3     89    'ttt'
4     99    'ttt'
5    210  'false'
```

Comment: it should remove both duplicates of true and false not just false value

Answer (score 1):

All you need is adding an additional filter for `[true, false]`.

```py
>>> df["before"] = df["col_b"].shift()
>>> df
   col_a  col_b before
0     21   true    NaN
1     25   true   true
2     76    abc   true
3     89    ttt    abc
4     99    ttt    ttt
5    210  false    ttt
6    211  false  false
7    212  false  false
>>> df[~((df["col_b"] == df["before"]) & (df["before"].isin(["true", "false"])))].drop(["before"], axis="columns")
   col_a  col_b
0     21   true
2     76    abc
3     89    ttt
4     99    ttt
5    210  false
```